# Codenameone Subscription

Tags: codenameone

I'd like to ask the following question: Consider, for example, that I buy the PROFESSIONAL subscription. After a while (a few months or so) I decide to cancel my subscription... what happens then with the APPs I already developed with CODENAMEONE? will they continue to be available on Google Play Store and / Or Apple Apps Store? My main concern is regarding the push-notification functionalities... That is, would the already published apps in Play Store and/or App Store remain fully functional?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The only exception would be that if you used push notification you will no longer be able to send new push messages to the app. Otherwise everything will keep working as usual and you can keep selling your app with no licensing restriction or anything.